# I am getting python errors for regular shell commands

Tags: ubuntu, python

The picture of the python error:

[image: picture of the python error]

This is just normal shell, i don't know why i am getting python errors and not command not found errors.

Comment: You are getting Python errors because the command is written in Python. The Python code needs a module named "apt_pkg", which is either not installed or whose location is unknown to the Python code. I suppose the name of the failing command is not "invalidcommand". To help you, more information is needed, in particular which commands fail, and on which distro you experience the failures. Add that to the question

Comment: `command-not-found` is part of the standard installation of Ubuntu, configured as the default handler for the case where the shell already searched the path and found no match for the supplied command.

Answer (score -1):

> This is just normal shell

I disagree.
I've been "mucking about" with Unix and Linux flavours for almost 20 years now and have never come across an **invalidcommand** utility.

Try this:

```
file invalidcommand
```

The **file** command tells you what "kind" of file(s) its arguments is/are.
In this case it will, almost *certainly*, mention Python.

Shells, like bash, *interpret* the text you enter into something that the Linux kernel can *execute*.  In this case, the shell "peeks" into the top of the file "invalidcommand" and reads the "[SheBang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))" line, which tells the shell *how* the file needs to be executed.  In this case, that line will mention Python.  The shell then fires up an instance of python and throws the file at it.

In this way, utilities can be written in just about any language you like and consumed by any shell.

Once the Python script is up and running, *it* then hits a problem.
It is complaining about a missing package.  I assume that the "invalidcommand" python script issues the "import apt_pkg" command, but this package is not installed on your system.

Comment: not `invalidcommand` is using python, the failed attempt at calling that name is what makes the shell turn to the c-n-f hook and *that* in turn is using python.

Comment: ^ This, i was using invaid command as a actual invalid command, not trying to actually invoke it, that's the entire point of this issue.